# Stale Element found error while trying to use Selenium Web Scraper on the Home Depot website

Tags: javascript, selenium-webdriver

I have been dealing with an issue of getting stale elements while attempting to web scrape the home depot wood and composites page using Selenium Web Driver. I have tried multiple solutions including adding a waitForStableElemets method. I'm not sure if the error is generating from that method or from the wood_and_composites method.

```
async function wood_and_composites(){
    let driver = await new Builder().forBrowser("chrome").build();
    //console.log(driver.toString())

    //driver.get("https://www.ebay.com");//test to make sure it works
    driver.get("https://www.homedepot.com/b/Building-Materials/N-5yc1vZaqns"); //goes to the building materials page of home depot

     const cardTitles = await driver.findElements(By.className("etchVisualNavigationStory__card__title"));//should be the title of each component on the page

    //iterates through all the cardTitles on the website provided
    for(const item of cardTitles){
        const title = await item.getText();
        //console.log(title)
        //checks to see if an item matches the label "Lumber" and then clicks it
        if(title.includes("Lumber")){
            await item.click();
            //console.log("Lumber has been found and has been selected"); //TEST STATEMENT
            //goes to page consisting of all lumber and composites.
            const sidebar = await driver.wait(until.elementLocated(By.className("navigational-layout__side-navigation")), 10000);
            //the .wait() should wait 10 seconds before looking for the sidebar component to ensure everything is loaded in correctly.
            const unorderedList = sidebar.findElement(By.tagName("ul"));
            const listItems = await unorderedList.findElements(By.tagName("li"));
            //checks to see if the sidebar contains the link for all lumber and composites
            for(const listItem of listItems){
                const itemText = await listItem.getText();
                //console.log(itemText);
                if(itemText.includes("Shop All Lumber & Composites")) {
                    await listItem.click();
                    //attempts to find all the prices on the page
                    const woodPrices = await driver.wait(until.elementsLocated(By.css(".price-format__main-price")), 10000);
                    const prices = await driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'price-format__main-price')] | //*[@id='bulk-price']"));
                    const names = await driver.findElements(By.xpath("//div[contains(@class, 'product-header__title--clamp--4y7oa product-header__title--fourline--4y7oa')]"));

                    // Wait for all elements to be visible
                    // Function to handle stale elements and ensure they are visible
                    const waitForStableElements = async (elements) => {
                        return driver.wait(async () => {
                            const refreshedElements = await Promise.all(elements.map(async (el) => {
                                try {
                                    const displayed = await el.isDisplayed();
                                    if (!displayed) {
                                        const parent = await el.findElement(By.xpath("./.."));
                                        return parent.isDisplayed();
                                    }
                                    return displayed;
                                } catch (error) {
                                    return false; // Element is stale or no longer present
                                }
                            }));
                            return refreshedElements.every(Boolean);
                        }, 20000);
                    };

                    // Wait for all elements to stabilize
                    await waitForStableElements(names);

                    //USED TO FORMAT THE STRING SO THE PRICE AND NAME ARE TOGETHER
                    //if (prices.length === names.length) { //currently there are 20 prices and 12 names for some reason
                    for (let i = 0; i < names.length && i+1 < prices.length; i++) {
                        const cost = await prices[i+1].getText(); // Use i+1 for prices
                        const dollars = cost.slice(0, cost.length - 2);
                        const cents = cost.slice(cost.length - 2);
                        const formattedPrice = dollars + "." + cents;

                        const name = await names[i].getText();

                        const output = `Price: ${formattedPrice} Product: ${name}`;
                        console.log(output);
                    }
                }
            }
            break;
        }
    }

     setInterval(function(){
         driver.close();
    }, 15000)
}
```

With the addition of the waitForStableElements method i tried to refresh the stale elements on the page, so that they could be retrieved. i am able to find 20 prices and 12 product names, but there should be 24 total on the first page. I am not sure why there are still stale elements being found.